# Variable returning NULL in IBAction xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm in a real pickle here ill try to make it short....

- I have a screen where the currentuser types in another users username. Hits the `UIButton` which takes you to the `second view controller` and sends the variable (the username typed in the textfeild) to the new `UIViewController`..
- I can log the `userID` (the one that was searched) so the variable is going between `views`, however on this screen i can type a message to that user from the current user and hit an `IBAction button` which sends it to **Parse.com**
- When i hit the button the app crashes and i get the error "Cannot do a comparison query for type **NULL**" after a few minutes i derived at the conclusion that the variable inside my `IBAction` is **NULL** however above in the `viewDidAppear`, it is equal to the correct value.

---

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     NSString *usernameID = [self.userField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"customUserDetails"])
    {
            NSString *userID = usernameID;
            customSearchViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc.userIDnew = userID;
    }
}
```

Im guessing i need a global variable on my `new view controller`? I have synthesised it.

Also another weird thing is that is only `crashes` on my device, on the simulator it works fine?

```
- (IBAction)sendMessageButton:(id)sender {

    if ([userIDnew length] != 0) {

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:userIDnew];
    PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];
```

The above is the problem area! the variable "`userIDnew`" is `NULL`!

Comment: have you check that usernameID is not null ?

Comment: Add zombie and exception breakpoint to know exact error.

Comment: Try accessing it via self.userIDnew rather than accessing the iVar directly